# An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(article: Article) : Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles")
    fun getAllArticles(): LiveData<List<Article>>

    @DELETE
    suspend fun deleteArticles(article: Article)
}
```

Hi! On running this code, I get the following error:
An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery
Please help me with this

Comment: I think that DELETE annotation could be the retrofit one, for Room the right annotation is Delete (in lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

@JesúsBarrera from the comments is correct. check your imports. the annotation should be like this

```
@Delete
```

android studio will probably import this

```
import androidx.room.*
```

if not already present

Answer (score 0):

You entered wrong annotation

replace

```
@DELETE
```

to

```
@Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I just forget to annotate the method with @Insert.

```kotlin
fun insertAll(postDbModels: Array<PostDbModel>)
```

Just adding @Insert fixed this.

```kotlin
@Insert
fun insertAll(postDbModels: Array<PostDbModel>)
```